# Run bat file, from bash, in a new window and wait for response

Tags: batch-file, cmd, git-bash

I want to run a new cmd, in a new window, which runs a bat file, from inside a bash shell. In my sh I tried this command.

```
start /wait  "$(pwd)\Tools\mybat.bat"
```

My bat runs successfully but my shell does not wait for it's completion. I guess this is because the `/wait` applies to `start` and not to the bat execution. Is there anyway to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The path can be converted to something bash understands and executed.

```
 cmd.exe /C start /W "" cmd.exe /C "$(cygpath -m $(pwd))/Tools/mybat.bat"
```